# Python use global variable inside a multiprocessing thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to use a variable inside two functions in two different multiprocessing threads, but it seems that the variable can't be shared...

```
import multiprocessing

threads = []
counter = 0

def my_function():
    global counter
    while True:
        counter += 1

def my_function_two():
    global counter
    while True:
        print(counter)


threads.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=my_function))
threads.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=my_function_two))

for j in threads:
    j.start()

for j in threads:
    j.join()
```

I saw different questions about sharing global variables in threads but none of them are helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Those aren't threads. If they were, the variable would have been shared. `multiprocessing` isn't based on threads.

Comment: You need to decide what you really want - threads or subprocesses. BTW - Your attempt to join is pointless as both processes are in infinite loops - i.e., they'll never end naturally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my code

```
import threading

threads = []
counter = 0

def my_function():
    global counter
    while True:
        counter += 1

def my_function_two():
    global counter
    while True:
        print(counter)


threads.append(threading.Thread(target=my_function))
threads.append(threading.Thread(target=my_function_two))

for j in threads:
    j.start()

for j in threads:
    j.join()
```